# libzbarjni.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening

Tags: android, zbar

In my barcode scanner application, using zbar lib for scanning barcode. It is thowing runtime exception as OutOfMemoryError.

Anybody please help to resolve this issue.

logcat:

```
2-16 13:06:01.635: W/linker(15501): libzbarjni.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.

12-16 13:06:06.483: E/art(15501): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 53654136 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 47MB until OOM"
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501): Error reporting crash
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 53654136 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 47MB until OOM
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
12-16 13:06:06.483: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Looks like your library is not very efficient on memory, which is crucial for Android applications. Maybe you could take a look at [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/) instead.

Comment: yes that would be the option but have used zbar lib by thinking of it is much more faster and efficient than zxing.

Comment: I haven't heard about zbar before, but I know for a fact that ZXing is used for scanning bar codes / QR codes in many android apps. Besides, you shouldn't optimize prematurely. Try ZXing and only consider other options once you have evidence that it doesn't perform fast enough.

Comment: I agreed but in zxing it needs a alot customization for camera as per our app. and its easy in zbar.Nways thanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error on some devices because of memory issues. And I resolved it by importing the zbar whole lib code in workspace and using zbar lib app as lib from workspace instead of adding/keeping lib(.jar) in my own application.