# An app using zbar library for scanning QR codes is getting crash.

Tags: android, zbar

I am trying to run the QR scanner app downloaded from 
http://kvenkataprasad.blogspot.in/2015/01/bar-code-and-qr-code-scanner-example.html?showComment=1449051540990#c226949441944394510

App getting started but when I am clicking the scan button, the app get crashed.
Following the log of crash.

```
 13239-13239/com.kvprasad.zbarbarcodescanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kvprasad.zbarbarcodescanner, PID: 13239
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.kvprasad.zbarbarcodescanner-1/lib/arm/libzbarjni.so: has text relocations
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
        at net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.kvprasad.zbarbarcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.initControls(BarcodeScanner.java:52)
        at com.kvprasad.zbarbarcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.onCreate(BarcodeScanner.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am not getting the main issue behind crashing because I am a newbie in android. Please guide me to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500458/libzbarjni-so-has-text-relocations-this-is-wasting-memory-and-prevents-security)

Comment: your code for button click?

Comment: scannerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scannerButton);

        scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });